# Play audio from video in lock screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video, appstore-approval, background-audio

I have an app where I want to play audio in the background. The trick is that there are NO audio tracks by them selves. There is only video, which is where the associated audio is coming from.

I added the following to my App Delegate:

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                error: &setCategoryError];
```

and this to my plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

However, Apple rejected my app this morning for having "background audio" in my `info.plist`. Even after I explained to them it was so I could play the videos via headphones/airplay when the device is locked.

I've researched this subject a number of times now and this is the only way I have found that looks like it would get approved by the app store yet, here I am getting rejected. What's the problem? Does anyone know how to accomplish background audio (from video) in a way that will get me approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the screen is "off" you double tap the home button and hit play. This will 1) play audio or 2) play video/audio to apple tv. After explaining this to Apple (irony) they let me resubmit the app and accepted it.